# why "Lines and planes through the origin, and only lines and planes through the origin, can be expressed as spans."?

Tags: linear-algebra

why we say Lines and planes through the origin, and only lines and planes through the origin, can be expressed as spans? what about the lines and planes that don't pass the origin? I am so confused..

Answer (score 2):

A line through the origin is all multiples of a vector.  A plane through the origin is all multiples of two vectors added together.
Any other line is one vector plus all mutiples of a second.  Any other plane is one vector plus all multiples of two other vectors.
So the ones through the origin are slightly simpler, and worth studying on their own for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Spans are subspaces and as such, they have to include the $0$ vector. The line $$y=ax+b$$ does not  include the vector $(0,0)$ unless $b=0$

Similarly, the plane $$z=ax+by +c$$ does not inlcude $(0,0,0)$ unless $c=0$.
The other issue with the lines and planes which do not pass through the origin is closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Only lines and planes through the origin  make a subspace of $R^n$
all other planes and lines do not include the 0 vector. and a vector space has to include 0

Answer (score 0):

When you will learn to use the [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) you will see that the difference "disappears" and geometry shows up in all its beauty, thanks to homogeneity and dualities.
I would suggest to start and dwell in it the sooner that you can.